# Login with Twitter Apollo GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, oauth, graphql, passport.js, apollo

I have been researching last few days how to integrate Twitter login with Passport into GraphQL application and I found out that there is no complete example on internet.

The closest I found is this [tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-nail-social-authentication-in-graphql-27943aee5dce/), but this only the backend, and for React frontend he is mentioning this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@alexanderleon/implement-social-authentication-with-react-restful-api-9b44f4714fa) which is for the REST and using this [component](https://github.com/GenFirst/react-twitter-auth#readme) which accepts two restful links as props. So basically there is no React component that accepts mutation as a prop that I could use.

I could use Express server in parallel with Apollo just for REST auth routes to store user in db but that would really be not nice.

I wonder how no one met a need to use social login in GraphQL application and why there are basically no examples out there?